# Delete [] caused free() libc error

Tags: c++, dynamic

I do not understand why the delete [] d_ caused free() libc error, even though the d_ ptr was not modified and refers to the first array element given by new. I understand that the d_ pointer cannot be modified and because new dynamic array assignment, it has to be deleted by delete [] ptr.

Error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08458008 *** 
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x70c91)[0xb753bc91]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x724f8)[0xb753d4f8]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xb754063d]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x1f)[0xb76c14bf]
./a.out[0x804887d]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0xb74e1e46]
./a.out[0x8048751]
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

class CombinationGenerator{
    private:
        unsigned int *d_;

    public:
        CombinationGenerator(){

    }

    void Generate(unsigned int a[], unsigned int n, unsigned int r){

        d_ = new unsigned int[r];

        Combi(a,0,n,d_,0,r);

        delete [] d_;
    }

    void Combi(unsigned int a[],unsigned int start, unsigned int n,
           unsigned int *d,unsigned int index, unsigned int r){

        if(n==r||index==r){
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                std::cout << d[i];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        for(int i=start;i<n&&(n-i)>=(r-index);i++){

            d[index] = a[i];

            Combi(a,i+1,n,d,index+1,r);
        }
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    CombinationGenerator generator;

    unsigned int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    generator.Generate(a,5,3);
}
```

Comment: I bet `d[index] =` writes beyond the range

Comment: How did you trace that back to the `delete`? It seems fine by me, I'd rather check that your indices are correct when accessing your arrays in your recursive function.

Comment: Please format your code and use descriptive names. It is painful to read your code.

Comment: Replace your `unsigned int *d_` with a `std::vector<unsigned int> d_` and you will get bounds checking in debug builds when *writing* to the array (helping you debug that code), not only later during free. Also: don't use a member variable where a local variable would be sufficient.

Comment: No, the if statement should ensure that d[index] does not exceed r

Comment: `i<n&&(n-i)>=(r-index)` evaluates to `true` when `i=3`, `n=5`, `r=3`, and `index=3`, which will cause you to write out of bounds. Since I have no idea what those variables are supposed to mean, it is difficult to give a correct resolution.

Comment: for me it is fine with no memory problem, used valgrind? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/254f7de5bba75ff1

Comment: tested. does not matter if it is a member or local variable for d

Comment: @EthanLim You're continuing into the loop after the conditional, and assigning to `d[3]`.

Comment: @RedAlert when index==r, it would not reach the for loop

Comment: @molbdnilo the problem I have is index will never be 3 in the first place

Comment: Got it, yes indeed it was out of memory at the last iteration of the last recursion when index = 3.

Comment: This is a stupid mistake, easily solved.

Comment: Just something to think about, managing the memory yourself is prone to errors. You may want an [alternative approach using `std::vector<>`](http://ideone.com/Lu1wEp). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you allocate 3 elements which index 0,1,2 but the line

```
 d[index] = a[i];
```

will cause invalid write of size 4 when index=3
your code will not have error if you change the line

```
d_ = new unsigned int[r];
```

to

```
d_ = new unsigned int[r+1];
```

Comment: Or I just return from the recursion. Again, my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

class CombinationGenerator{
    private:
        unsigned int *d_;
    public:
        CombinationGenerator(){}

    void Generate(unsigned int a[], unsigned int n, unsigned int r){

        d_ = new unsigned int[r];

        Combi(a,0,n,d_,0,r);

        delete [] d_;
    }

    void Combi(unsigned int a[],unsigned int start, unsigned int n,
           unsigned int *d,unsigned int index, unsigned int r){

        if(n==r||index==r){
            for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
                std::cout << d[i];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;

            return;
        }

        for(int i=start;i<n&&(n-i)>=(r-index);i++){

            d[index] = a[i];

            Combi(a,i+1,n,d,index+1,r);
        }
    }
};


 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   CombinationGenerator generator;

   unsigned int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

   generator.Generate(a,5,3);
}
```